nestjs bullmq consumer does not process the job
I have 2 Nodejs services that communicate using Bullmq with each other. Unfortunately, the processor function is not invoked and all the messages lie as waiting in the queue as I check with Bullboard. However, I could not found the reason because TestConsumer is in the providers list of the ÀppModule`. I appreciate any help.
App module
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { BullModule, InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { TestConsumer } from './queue/test.consumer';
import { Queue } from 'bull';

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRoot({
      redis: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
      },
    }),
    BullModule.registerQueue({
      name: 'test',
      url: 'redis://localhost:6379',
    }),
  ],
  providers: [TestConsumer, AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(@InjectQueue('test') private testQueue: Queue) {
    this.testQueue.getJobCounts().then(console.log);
  }
}


And consumer
import { OnQueueActive, Process, Processor } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Job } from 'bull';

@Processor('test')
export class TestConsumer {
  @OnQueueActive()
  onActive(job: Job) {
    console.log(
      `Processing job ${job.id} of type ${job.name} with data ${job.data}...`,
    );
  }

  @Process()
  async process(job: Job): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Processing job');
    const jobData = job.data;
    console.log('Processing job', jobData);
  }
}

I could not get any logs from the process function.

Did you first add a job to the testQueue in the app module, e.g in the app module constructor:
  constructor(@InjectQueue('test') private testQueue: Queue) {
    this.testQueue.add({ foo: 'bar'})
    this.testQueue.getJobCounts().then(console.log);
  }

